# System.DivideByZeroException without division

Tags: c#, c++, video, aforge

I am using this code to capture short bursts of video from a connected camera:

```
private void Show() {
    if (videoDevice != null) {
        videoDevice.VideoResolution = capabilities[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];
        size = ((Size) comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        videoDevice.NewFrame += new AForge.Video.NewFrameEventHandler(Frame);
        videoDevice.Start();
    }
}
private void Frame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs e) {
    if (count > 7 && !motion) {
        urame = 0;
        b = ((Bitmap) e.Frame.Clone());
        if (detector.ProcessFrame(b) > 0.02) {
            motion = true;
            writer.Open(@"C:\Users\Home\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CCTV\CCTV\bin\wesdgzufjw3.mp4", size.Width, size.Height, 30, VideoCodec.MSMPEG4v3);
        }
    } 
    else if (motion) {
        b = ((Bitmap) e.Frame.Clone());
        writer.WriteVideoFrame(b);
        if (detector.ProcessFrame(b) < 0.02) {
            motion = false;
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
    count++;
}
```

But for some reason, when motion is detected, visual studio throws an error saying that:

> "An exception of type 'System.DivideByZeroException' occurred in AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll but was not handled in user code"

I have checked my code for "bad divisions" and out of desperation I've removed **all** arithmetic from my code. A friend of mine used the exact same lib - AForge.Video.FFMPEG - in one of his projects a few weeks ago and didn't encounter any error like this.

The problem is that the error doesn't tell what could be wrong.. division could be in the lib, in a method I've used, heck, even ToString() must use some sort of division..

**Note:** I've added a tag for c++ because 1) Aforge is mostly written in c++ and 2) a few minutes before this error I got an error saying that the VS2013 C# debugger can't debug C++ and that an error had occurred in C++

Comment: It's not in your code, it's in AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll.  Is your size.width or height zero?

Comment: Sounds like you are sending bad data to the library.

Comment: @robinson I changed size.width and size.height to 1280 and 720 respectively. Now it's throwing an access voilation exception..